# Javascript click event not working in Safari, but functions in other browsers

Tags: javascript, safari, click

It seems like this is a common problem mentioned here, but I've tried every similar solution I've found here with no luck. My site works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not Safari. I've attached an event listener to a button with ID "spinTheWheel"

```
document.getElementById('spinTheWheel').addEventListener('click', randomRestaurant);
```

randomRestaurant() cues a function with a switch case, but clicking the button in Safari always defaults to case 0 before not responding to clicks anymore.

I've tried adding {pointer: cursor} to the button's CSS values; tried calling the randomRestaurant() function inline in the HTML code; tried swapping .addEventListener for .click(); and fiddled with code from other StackOverflow answers.

Weirdly, the button has no problem responding to clicks once I open up Safari developer tools.

HTML Code

```
  <section class="mainSect">
    <button id="spinTheWheel" type="button" name="spinTheWheel" tabindex="0" onfocus="javascript:randomRestaurant()">Save Me from Myself!</button>
  </section>
```

CSS Code

```
.mainSect{
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 2em 30em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

#spinTheWheel{
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: 0em 2em 0 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
function randomRestaurant(){
  let choice = Math.round(Math.random()*14)

  switch (choice) {
    case choice=0:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Maybe some Indian?';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/indian-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=1:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='How about some Italian?';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/italian-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=2:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='There\'s nothing better than some pub grub!';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/wings-burgers-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=3:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='You can\'t beat good Mexican food.';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/mexican-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=4:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='Tonight might be the night for some Chinese takeout.';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/chinese-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=5:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='You can\'t beat good Japanese food.';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/japanese-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=6:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='Did you say you wanted Thai? Or did I just read your mind?';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/thai-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=7:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='Let\'s be honest Fast food could hit the spot right now.';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/fast-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=8:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='You\'d better grab some napkins, because I see barbeque in your future.';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/barbeque-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=9:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'You can\'t beat Soul food.';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/soul-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=10:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='Ready for a flavor explosion? How about Jamaican?';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/jamaican-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=11:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='Do I smell lemon and oregano? Or am I just getting Mediterranean food vibes from you?';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/mediterranean-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=12:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='No matter the hour, it\'s breakfast o\'clock somewhere!';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/breakfast-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=13:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='Nothing beats a good Deli Sandwich.';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/deli-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice=14:
      document.getElementById('result').innerText ='You\'re so sweet. Get some Dessert to match.';
      document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/dessert-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    default:
      console.log('err')
  }
  document.getElementById('spinTheWheel').innerText = 'Let\'s try something else';
}
```

Comment: Please add the code for the function and any HTML/CSS that is in play as well.

Comment: @dalelandry just updated. Please let me know if larger snippets would be helpful.

Comment: `randomRestaurant()` can you add this function please?

Comment: @dalelandry apologies--updated!

Comment: Try placing just below you switch statement in your javascript file... `document.getElementById('spinTheWheel').addEventListener('focus', randomRestaurant)` and remove the global handler call in your html element button.

Comment: If you want the button to also trigger the function, go ahead and make a separate event handler for it as well and simply pass the function into its call back section as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in Safari and see if it is working for you. I have disabled the images as there is only local reference to them and I have also removed the global HTML focus and added a `mouseover` event for the buttons DOM element

```js
const button = document.getElementById('spinTheWheel')
const result = document.getElementById('result')
button.addEventListener('mouseover', randomRestaurant)
const selectBtn = document.querySelector('.select-rest')

function selectFood(type) {    
    selectBtn.classList.remove('hidden')
    selectBtn.textContent = `Select ${type} ?`
    selectBtn.dataset.id = type
}

function randomRestaurant(e) {
  let choice = ~~Math.round(Math.random() * 14)
  let type = '';

  switch (choice) {
    case choice = 0:
      type = 'Indian';
      result.innerText = 'Maybe some Indian?';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/indian-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 1:
      type = 'Italian';
      result.innerText = 'How about some Italian?';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/italian-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 2:
      type = 'Pub Grub';
      result.innerText = 'There\'s nothing better than some pub grub!';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/wings-burgers-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 3:
      type = 'Mexican';
      result.innerText = 'You can\'t beat good Mexican food.';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/mexican-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 4:
      type = 'Chinese';
      result.innerText = 'Tonight might be the night for some Chinese takeout.';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/chinese-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 5:
      type = 'Japanese';
      result.innerText = 'You can\'t beat good Japanese food.';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/japanese-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 6:
      type = 'Thai';
      result.innerText = 'Did you say you wanted Thai? Or did I just read your mind?';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/thai-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 7:
      type = 'Fast food';
      result.innerText = 'Let\'s be honest Fast food could hit the spot right now.';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/fast-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 8:
      type = 'BBQ';
      result.innerText = 'You\'d better grab some napkins, because I see barbeque in your future.';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/barbeque-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 9:
      type = 'Soul';
      result.innerText = 'You can\'t beat Soul food.';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/soul-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 10:
      type = 'Jamaican';
      result.innerText = 'Ready for a flavor explosion? How about Jamaican?';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/jamaican-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 11:
      type = 'Mediterranean';
      result.innerText = 'Do I smell lemon and oregano? Or am I just getting Mediterranean food vibes from you?';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/mediterranean-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 12:
      type = 'Breakfast';
      result.innerText = 'No matter the hour, it\'s breakfast o\'clock somewhere!';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/breakfast-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 13:
      type = 'Deli';
      result.innerText = 'Nothing beats a good Deli Sandwich.';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/deli-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    case choice = 14:
      type = 'Dessert';
      result.innerText = 'You\'re so sweet. Get some Dessert to match.';
      //document.getElementById('foodImg').src = "img/dessert-food-pic.jpg";
      break;
    default:
      console.log('err')
  }
  document.getElementById('spinTheWheel').innerText = 'Let\'s try something else';
  selectFood(type)
  if (document.querySelector('.select-rest')) {
    document.querySelector('.select-rest').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      result.innerText = `Excellent choice: ${type} it is`
      selectBtn.classList.add('hidden')
    })
  }

}
```

```css
.mainSect {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 2em 30em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

#spinTheWheel {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: 0em 2em 0 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="mainSect">
  <button id="spinTheWheel" type="button" name="spinTheWheel" tabindex="0">Save Me from Myself!</button>
</section>

<div id="result"></div>
<button class="select-rest hidden" data-id=""></button>
```